# MVC3 Client side validation erratic/inconsistent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Server side validation works great but client side will not work on some fields.

Using :

```
"jquery-1.5.1.min.js"  
"modernizr-1.7.min.js"  
"jquery.validate.min.js"  
"jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js".
```

HTML5 semantic markup

MVC3, Razor, Code First

Class Data Annotations:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required, MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be {1} characters or less")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Range(20, 50, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public double Waist { get; set; }
```

View:

The view is strongly typed.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <span class="editor-label">  First Name </span>

    <span class="editor-field">

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)

    </span><br /><br />

    <span class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Waist): 20 to 50</span>

    <span class="editor-field">

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Waist)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Waist)

    </span><br /><br />
```

Client side validation works for Waist but not FirstName.  Server side works for both.

When I look at the source code Waist has a data-val-range.

data-val-range = "Waist must be between 20 and 50"

There is no data-val-range for FirstName.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Joe

I'm using IE9 64 bit.

Upon further investigation Required and String Length partially work.  I changed the Dataannotation attributes to this.

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]       [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be {2} to {1} characters")]     public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Now when I go to my edit view and clear the FirstName textbox and tab to the next I get no validation error.  If I then enter one character I get the StringLength message, when I subsequently clear the field I then get the Required message.  Getting closer but it is still not working correctly.

data-val-length= gets added to the source when I use StringLength

Comment: This is a test for the unread notification emails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MaxLength` and `MinLength` doesn't work with client side validation. You could use [StringLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) instead:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be {1} characters or less")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And there's a [MinimumLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.minimumlength.aspx) property that you could set if you wanted to simulate the `MinLength` attribute:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be between 10 and 30 characters")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems that you want to trigger the validation eagerly even if the form is not submitted. You could add the following script to achieve that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
        settngs.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
    });
</script>
```

---

UPDATE 2:

Here's a full example. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the internet template.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be {2} to {1} characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            FirstName = "foo"
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
        settngs.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin but neither one works.  Also the Required attribute is not working either.  And the Range attribute doesn't work if you edit another field where the validation fails.  Anybody have any information from MS about bugs in the MVC validation?

Comment: @Joe, no information about such bugs. Those attributes work perfectly fine for me with client side validation. I have used them multiple times without any issues.

Comment: They partially work.  See end of my updated post.  They do not work the first time.

Comment: @Joe, it looks that you are trying to trigger the validation when a field looses focus even if the form wasn't yet submitted. That's not how the unobtrusively validation is configured by default. You could change this behavior by adding a setting as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: I get it now that this is the default behavior.  I guess it is a philosophical debate as to whether it should be eager (as you called it) or not.  I placed your code in the edit view right after the unobstursive script and it did not change the behavior. If I delete the FirstName content and tab out of the field I still do not get an error message.  Is this where you intended the code to go?  Current DataAnnotation is:                             [Required, StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First Name required, must be {2} to {1} characters")]

Comment: Ignore prior comment.  I get it now that this is the default behavior.  I guess it is a philosophical debate as to whether it should be eager (as you called it) or not.  I placed your code in the edit view right after the unobstursive script and got the following Script Error.
Error: Unable to get value of the property ‘settings’: object is null or undefined. Just learning Java script, is 'form' supposed to be set to some value? I'm using a standard Razor template generated view to display the fields @using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>

Comment: @Joe, I don't know why your code doesn't work. I am unable to reproduce the error. I have updated my answer once again and posted a step by step guide to a full working example.

Comment: Your code works.  I'm using a @helper Script to load my validate and unobtursive and they were loading after your code.  Once I fixed that it worked like a charm.  Thank you for all the help.

Comment: To sum it all up Maxlength doesn't work for client-side validation, use StringLength instead.  The default behavior of jquery.validate.unobtrusive is not to display validation errors until after a submit.  If you want "eager" validation use Darin's script code snippet.